# VSCode How do I install Laravel code completions?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I'm in the process of learning Laravel 6.0 and I'm using the current version of VSCode to write my code. At the moment, my instance of VSCode doesn't offer any Laravel code completions. How do I tell VSCode to offer those completions? If there is no such setting, is there some kind of add-on for VSCode that provides code completions for Laravel? Where would I find this add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel5-snippets) works for Laravel 6 because the features are still there.

For PHP, [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) is really great for VSCode.

Comment: Just do your research more before asking most questions. I guess if you'd gone to the visual studio marketplace you would have seen the extensions